# UISwitch on and off by system and by user

Tags: ios, ios7, uiswitch

My table view has 2 sections where in the first section has a switch and other section has couple of table view cells. When the switch if on, the cells should be visible and selected and when the switch is off the cells should be hidden.

If my cellForRowAtIndexPath for my first section I execute a selector when the user changes the switch state as per below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPathForFirstSection
{
    [self.tableViewFirstCell.mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(changeState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return self.tableViewFirstCell;
}
```

***changeStateMethod:***

```
- (void)changeState:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    if ([sender isOn])
    {
        //Show other section and select its cells.
    }

    // Reload the table view.
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    if (![sender isOn])
    {
        // Collect the selected cells data and hide the section.
    }
}
```

There are scenarios when the user lands on the view for the first time, the system should handle changing the state of the switch. If the switch should be made ON I have:

```
[self.tableViewFirstCell.mySwitch setOn:YES animated:YES]; or to make it OFF I have:

[self.tableViewFirstCell.mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
```

***QUESTION:***
So whether the switch is changed by the system or by the user, the logic to be executed after changing the state of the switch is same in both the cases. In short, when the user changes the switch the selector method gets called, but when the system changes the state is there a way I can call the selector which figures out what state is the switch changed to and then execute the logic appropriately as it does when the user changes the switch?

For example: When the user changes the switch state to ON, logic inside "`if ([sender isOn])`" gets executed. I want to execute this logic when the system changes the state of the switch to ON.

Comment: What do you mean by "the system changes the state of the switch"? Do you mean when your code explicitly changes the state?

Comment: Yes by system I mean code changes the state.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate methods are only called when a user interacts with the control. If you want the same event processed when you change the state via code, simple call the event handler yourself.

```
[self.tableViewFirstCell.mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
[self changeState:self.tableViewFirstCell.mySwitch];
```

That's it. Nice and simple.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that I should explicitly call the "changeState" method, but is there a way I can add the selector call in "[self.tableViewFirstCell.mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES]" ? If not then I will use the explicit call to "changeState" method.

Comment: No, you need to make the two calls.